# Задача про призовые места, что я делаю не так?

Tags: python, строки

Дана задача :

> В новом сезоне за первенство в велогонках вновь борются лучшие из
> лучших. Протяжённость заключительной трассы — 43872м, и все хотят
> знать, кто получит золотую медаль.
>
> Нам известны средние скорости трёх претендентов на победу – Пети, Васи
> и Толи. Кто из них победит?
>
> Формат ввода: В первой строке записана средняя скорость Пети. Во
> второй — Васи. В третьей — Толи.
>
> Формат вывода: Красивый пьедестал (ширина ступеней 8 символов).

Написал к ней такой код на Python:

```
#Получаю на вход значения средних скоростей
petya_speed = int(input())
vasya_speed = int(input())
tolya_speed = int(input())
#Сортирую скорости от меньшей к большей
boys = sorted([petya_speed, vasya_speed, tolya_speed])

#Функция по скорости определяет имя мальчика
def whoIs(speed):
    if speed == petya_speed:
        return 'Петя'
    elif speed == vasya_speed:
        return 'Вася'
    else:
        return 'Толя'

#Записываю призовые места в переменные
first = whoIs(boys[2])
second = whoIs(boys[1])
third = whoIs(boys[0])
#Вывожу результат
print(f'''
          {first}          
  {second}  
                  {third}  
   II      I      III   
''')
```

Однако система тестирования не принимает его, будьте добры, объясните что я делаю не так ?

Comment: лишние пробелы после {third} ? а у вас "красивый"  пьедестал ?

Comment: @Интик убрал, ничего не поменялось, в vs code подсчитал количество символов, на всю строку их 24, как и должно быть по условию

Answer (score 2, accepted):

перед выводом и после него стояли знаки возврата каретки
исправленную часть привожу ниже

```
#Вывожу результат
print(f'''          {first}          
  {second}  
                  {third}  
   II      I      III   ''')
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение с изученными для этого урока операторами

```
petya = int(input())
vasya = int(input())
tolya = int(input())

if petya > vasya:
    if petya > tolya:
        mest1 = "Петя"
        if vasya > tolya:
            mest2 = "Вася"
            mest3 = "Толя"
        else:
            mest2 = "Толя"
            mest3 = "Вася"             
    elif tolya > petya:
        mest1 = "Толя"
        mest2 = "Петя"
        mest3 = "Вася"
elif vasya > petya:
    if vasya > tolya:
        mest1 = "Вася"
        if petya > tolya:
            mest2 = "Петя"
            mest3 = "Толя"
        else:
            mest2 = "Толя"
            mest3 = "Петя"
    else:
        mest1 = "Толя"
        mest2 = "Вася"
        mest3 = "Петя"
        
print("{:^8}{:^8}{:^8}".format(" ", mest1, " "))
print("{:^8}{:^8}{:^8}".format(mest2, " ", " "))
print("{:^8}{:^8}{:^8}".format(" ", " ", mest3))
print("{:^8}{:^8}{:^8}".format("II", "I", "III"))
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]